# Open Outlok with values filled in using ASP

Tags: asp-classic

i do one project in asp , in that i need to open a outlook express (with all fields are filled like from , to , sub , Body etc..)to send mail(i am aware of mailto:). Especially in Body i need to send a normal HTML file(Not as attachment) , Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

mailto: links. You can set things like

```
<a href="mailto:address?body=some_text;subject=Hi">Mail Me</a>
```

There's different parameters for different sections AND the parameters are limited to 255 characters so it might not be the best method.

Comment: Yes , But i need to send a html file , so it is more than 255 characters, Please help me to find the solution..

Comment: Tony, that should be an ampersand, not a semicolon. "mailto:mail@example.com?body=...&subject=...". Also, the limit is more than 255 characters, it is at least 1024 (probably 2048, asaik). However, HTML formatting will not work on mailto links.

Comment: I ran into problems with something like this and switching to ; fixed it for me. As for 255, that's just what I was told.

Answer (score 0):

what about using 'POST' ?

```
<form action="mailto:me@you.com" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="body" value="....." />
</form>
```

and submit it from JS?